# Get data from nodejs sails in JS/jQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sails.js, ejs

I'm trying to get the data that I have from the NodeJS and sails backend directly in jQuery, but I don't found how to do this.

NodeJS Backend :

```
var json = {dataNodeJS: records};
return res.view(json);
```

EJS frontend :

```
<span style="display: none;" id="dataForTable"><%= JSON.stringify(dataNodeJS) %></span>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var data = jQuery.parseJSON($('span#dataForTable').text());
        console.log(data);
    });
</script>
```

Actually, I get the data from NodeJS, I print it in the SPAN, and i get it in jQuery.

I want to know if it possible to get it directly in jQuery (or javascript instead obviously) ?

PS : I work in jQuery because I use some lib to manipulate the data.

Thank you :)

Comment: one word you need:ajax

Comment: You should be able to inject it directly into the `<script>` tag, e.g. `var data = <%- JSON.stringify(dataNodeJS) %>;`.

Comment: @skirtle It doesn't works. I've already try it. Tthe tag "<%%>" is only for the EJS (like JEE). It's the equivalent of <?php ?>.

Comment: @madalinivascu I don't know, my mate tell me it's not powerfull... How do you think to use it ?

Comment: @Azelytof It works fine so long as you do it in your EJS template. `<script>var data = <%- JSON.stringify(dataNodeJS) %>; console.log(data);</script>`.

Comment: @skirtle Oh ! my bad, I thought you write <%= and not <%-
Thank you very much ! It works :)